# В какой примитив будет преобразован объект `Date` при передаче в качестве аргумента: `new Date(new Date())`?

Tags: javascript

В какой примитив будет преобразован объект `Date` при передаче в качестве аргумента: `new Date(new Date())`?

Comment: А в чем проблема просто написать это в консоли? У меня получется `Date`

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, в том что вопрос был про внутренность конструктора Date, не то, что он возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии со [спецификацией](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-date-value), при вызове конструктора с одним параметром будут выполнены следующие действия:

Если у переданного параметра есть внутренний слот `[[DateValue]]`, тогда никакого приведения не происходит, просто берется значение этого слота и устанавливается в соответствующий слот нового объекта.

В противном случае к параметру применяется метод `ToPrimitive` и в случае, если вернулась строка - к ней применится `Date.parse`, иначе произойдет попытка привести к числу.

---

Таким образом ответом на вопрос:

> В какой примитив будет преобразован объект Date при передаче в качестве аргумента: `new Date(new Date())`?

будет: ни в какой, так как у `Date` есть внутренний слот `[[DateValue]]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364860/calling-the-date-constructor-with-a-date-object